# Problemas con solicitud dinámica Json ASP .Net

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Tengo un simulador de cálculos el cual mediante eventos `change` realiza una petición al controlador y este me devuelve una respuesta dinámica, de por si el codigo que tenia funcionaba y hacía la solicitud y me requerimiento correctamente, pero este consume mucha memoria del navegador o computador (Lo desconozco) y la pagina se ponía demasiado lenta hasta que en un punto las peticiones `Ajax` dejaban de funcionar, por lo cual opte por usa Json para realizarlo, use este [Ejemplo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/21130/como-mandar-un-json-a-una-vista-con-asp-net-mvc) pero en un punto de la ejecución tengo este error **Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto.**

De este modo realizó mi petición:

Modelo:

```
public class CalculosSolicitud
{
    public decimal ValorSolicitado { get; set; }
    public decimal ValorInteres { get; set; }
    public decimal ValorSeguro { get; set; }
    public decimal ValorEstudio { get; set; }
    public decimal ValorPlataforma { get; set; }
    public decimal ValorIva { get; set; }
    public decimal ValorTotal { get; set; }
}
```

Controlador a Json:

```
private List<CalculosSolicitud> ObtenerListaCalculos()
    {
        CalculosSolicitud rta = new CalculosSolicitud();
        liquidar = new Entity.Credito.Common.ResponseCreditoType();
        List<CalculosSolicitud> Datos = new List<CalculosSolicitud>()
        {
            new CalculosSolicitud() { ValorSolicitado = rta.ValorSolicitado = liquidar.solicitud.Valor },
            new CalculosSolicitud() { ValorSeguro = rta.ValorSeguro = liquidar.solicitud.ValorSeguro },
            new CalculosSolicitud() { ValorInteres = rta.ValorInteres = liquidar.solicitud.ValorInteres },
            new CalculosSolicitud() { ValorEstudio = rta.ValorEstudio = liquidar.solicitud.CostoEstudio },
            new CalculosSolicitud() { ValorPlataforma =  rta.ValorPlataforma = liquidar.solicitud.CostoPlataforma },
            new CalculosSolicitud() { ValorIva =  rta.ValorIva = liquidar.solicitud.IVA },
            new CalculosSolicitud() { ValorTotal =  rta.ValorTotal = liquidar.solicitud.Total }
        };
        return Datos;
    }
```

JsonResult:

```
public JsonResult LlamarJson(int Valor, int Plazo)
    {
        var output = ObtenerListaCalculos();
        return Json(output, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

En JavaScript:

```
RangoPlazoCredito.change(function () {
    CreditoPlazo.attr(Value, $(this).val());
    CreditoPlazo1.attr(Value, $(this).val());
    CreditoPlazo2.attr(Value, $(this).val());
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        traditional: true,
        async: false,
        cache: false,
        url: '/Home/LlamarJson',
        context: document.body,
        data: { Valor: RangoValorCredito.val(), Plazo: RangoPlazoCredito.val() },
        success: function (result) {
            alert(result);
            $("#ValorCreditoMostrar").html('');
            $("#ValorCreditoMostrar").append("<p> " + result.ValorSolicitado + " </p>");
        },
        error: function (xhr) {
            //debugger;
            console.log(xhr.responseText);
            console.log("Error has occurred..", xhr);
        }
    });
});
```

En el controlador `Json` Cuando defino la `List<CalculosSolicitud>` y su contenido es cuando me genera el error **Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto.**

**Edición**

Anteriormente estaba llenando los objetos de la siguiente manera:

```
public ActionResult CalcularSimulador(int Valor, int Plazo)
    {
        ParametrosInteresesModel model = new ParametrosInteresesModel();
        Entity.Credito.Common.RequestCreditoType req = llenarReq(Valor, Plazo);
        LlenarViewBag(req);
        model.req = req;
        model.calculosSolicitud = llenarObjCalculos();
        model.calculosCalendario = llenarObjetoCalculoCalendario(Valor, Plazo);
        return View("_viewCalculosParciales", model.calculosSolicitud);
    }
```

En el controlador index:

```
public ActionResult Index(ParametrosInteresesModel model)
    {
        Entity.Credito.Common.RequestCreditoType req = llenarReq(150000, 5);
        LlenarViewBag(req);
        model.req = req;
        model.calculosSolicitud = new CalculosSolicitud
        {
            ValorSolicitado = liquidar.solicitud.Valor,
            ValorEstudio = liquidar.solicitud.CostoEstudio,
            ValorInteres = liquidar.solicitud.ValorInteres,
            ValorIva = liquidar.solicitud.IVA,
            ValorPlataforma = liquidar.solicitud.CostoPlataforma,
            ValorSeguro = liquidar.solicitud.ValorSeguro,
            ValorTotal = liquidar.solicitud.Total

        };
        model.calculosCalendario = new CalculosCalendario
        {
            PlazoMaximo = parametro.parametro.PlazoMaximo,
            PlazoMinimo = parametro.parametro.PlazoMinimo,
            ValorMaximo = parametro.parametro.ValorMaximo,
            ValorMinimo = parametro.parametro.ValorMinimo,
            Valor = liquidar.solicitud.Valor,
            Valor1 = liquidar.solicitud.Valor,
            Valor2 = liquidar.solicitud.Valor,
            Plazo = liquidar.solicitud.Plazo,
            Plazo1 = liquidar.solicitud.Plazo,
            Plazo2 = liquidar.solicitud.Plazo
        };
        //MessageBox.Show(resultado.respuesta.Codigo.ToString() + " - " + resultado.respuesta.Mensaje);
        return View(model);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

La forma correcta es definir el tipo de tu lista vacía y posteriormente llenarla con los elementos de este tipo

```
List<CalculosSolicitud> Datos = new List<CalculosSolicitud>();
CalculosSolicitud item = new CalculosSolicitud
 { ValorSolicitado = liquidar.solicitud.Valor,
   ValorSeguro = liquidar.solicitud.ValorSeguro,
   ValorInteres = liquidar.solicitud.ValorInteres,
   ValorEstudio = liquidar.solicitud.CostoEstudio,
   ValorPlataforma = liquidar.solicitud.CostoPlataforma,
   ValorIva =  liquidar.solicitud.IVA,
   ValorTotal =  liquidar.solicitud.Total
};                        
Datos.Add(item);
```

Comment: `ValorTotal =  rta.ValorTotal = liquidar.solicitud.Total` desde el `rta.`  es como yo trato de traer los datos de una clase, de como lo estaba haciendo anteriormente, pero si realmente iria desde `liquidar`, una duda el controlador pelea por que no se retorna ningún valor ¿que parametro debo retornar ?

Comment: Listo, modifique mi respuesta para que quede acorde a lo que comentas, el error se establece ya que estas haciendo referencia a un objeto nulo, ahora con la forma que te comento para llenar el objeto y luego la lista, podrías debuguear para determinar si tu objeto liquidar contiene datos que quieres usar para llenar tu objeto del tipo CalculosSolicitud

Comment: Acabo de ampliar el codigo de como lo estaba haciendo antes, este modo si llena los objetos, con este modo me llegan los datos vacíos.